# Redirect to random domain in array?

Tags: javascript

Here's the current code I'm using:

```
var domainArray = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'bing.com'];
var rand_domain = domainArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * domainArray.length)];
window.location = "http://${rand_domain}/subfolder";
```

I want this to randomly redirect to one of these links:

```
http://google.com/subfolder
http://yahoo.com/subfolder
http://bing.com/subfolder
```

But instead, it's just redirecting here:

```
http://${rand_domain}/subfolder
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well you are not using a string literal so that would be your problem. The " needs to be `

Comment: `\`http://${rand_domain}/subfolder\``